# VBA Excel 2016 Runtime error 9: Index out of range

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write a VBA program for Excel where I can throw every kind of table into and at the End the program shows me similar values and a distinct list of all values from every field.

It works fine until the program reaches the marked point.

I already tried to use a fixed position like:

```
If Range("A1") = tabInhalt(1) Then
```

but then the whole program crashes.

```
Sub findSimilarValues()
 
'Variable to count number of  columns.
Dim colCount As Long
  'array to count the number of rows per column.
Dim rowCount(1000) As Long
'array to safe the distinct parts of the table into
Dim tabInhalt(1000) As Variant
'variable to count all filled fields of a table
Dim fldCount As Long
'this variable counts +1 if a string from Table already exists in the array
Dim pruef As Long
'array with a double alphabet: used for entering the right column
Dim alphabet() As Variant
alphabet = Array("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "AA", "AB", "AC", "AD", "AE", "AF", "AG", "AH", "AI", "AJ", "AK", "AL", "AM", "AN", "AO", "AP", "AQ", "AR", "AS", "AT", "AU", "AV", "AW", "AX", "AY", "AZ")
 
'for variables
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Dim l As Integer
Dim m As Integer
Dim n As Integer
 
Worksheets("Suchfeld").Select
 
'count columns
colCount = Worksheets("Suchfeld").Range("AZ3").End(xlToLeft).Column
 
    'count rows per column
    For i = 0 To colCount
       rowCount(i) = Worksheets("Suchfeld").Range(alphabet(i) + "1000").End(xlUp).Row
    Next i
 
       'rows per table
       For j = 0 To colCount
           fldCount = fldCount + rowCount(j)
       Next j
 
    'print out variables and arrays to check the Results
   ' Worksheets("Tabelle4").Range("A1") = colCount
   ' Dim o As Integer
   ' For o = 0 To colCount
   ' Worksheets("Tabelle4").Range(alphabet(o) + "2") = rowCount(o)
   ' Next o
   ' Worksheets("Tabelle4").Range("A3") = fldCount
 
          'fills the array with values/strings from the table, as long as the values are not in the array.
          For k = 0 To fldCount  'counts for the array
              pruef = 0     'the pruef variable counts +1 every if the tables value exists in the array.
              For l = 0 To colCount  'counts for the columns of the table.
                  For m = 3 To rowCount(l)   'counts for the number of rows per column.
                      For n = 0 To fldCount    'goes through the array to see if the value of the table is already in the array
 
                          If Range(alphabet(l) & m) = tabInhalt(n) Then ' <--Runtime error 9 : Index out of range
   pruef = pruef + 1
                          End If
 
                      Next n
 
                      If pruef = 0 Then
                        tabInhalt(k) = alphabet(l) & (m)
                      End If
 
                  Next m
              Next l
          Next k
```

Comment: It's hard for us to check the details. Have you checked the values of variables when it crashes? Perhaps `n` has exceeded 1000? It's not helped by you setting the sizes of arrays but then using them in variable loops. Either use the upper bound or `ubound` if the upper bound is likely to change.

Comment: In addition to what @SJR writes, there may be a simpler method of accomplishing your goal either in VBA using a Dictionary object, or with Power Query.  But you don't provide sufficient information for anyone to reproduce your problem, making advice difficult. Perhaps [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would give you some hints as to how to edit your question to improve it.